# Viewing last.fm stats over an arbitrary date range

Tags: last.fm

Is there any way to view your top artist/track stats between an arbitrary date range on last.fm (instead of being confined to "weekly snapshots")?  I don't believe there is a way on the site itself, but is there any webapp implementing the last.fm API that allows you to do this?

Comment: LastHistory for OSX (http://www.frederikseiffert.de/lasthistory/) can do some pretty advanced visualisations and stats. It's not a web app though and is only available on OSX so I won't add it as an answer, it's worth a look if its applicable to you though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [LastGraph](http://lastgraph3.aeracode.org/) for a service that does colourful graphs of your Last.FM listening/scrobbling history over arbitrary time periods.